# Issue: Violation of Permissions policy

Tags: android, permissions, sms, policy

Issue: Violation of Permissions policy
After reviewing your app, we found that it doesn’t qualify to use the requested permissions for the following reason(s):

-Based on our review, we found your app’s expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler), Default Phone handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler). Please remove these permissions from your app.
    -Default handler capability was listed on your declaration form, but your app does not appear to have default handler capability. Please submit a revised declaration form.

How to unchecked all Permissions Declaration Form checkboxes and save

Comment: See this https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303

Comment: I have used sms api and removed sms and call related permisions but not worked.

Comment: Then re-confirm once that you removed your old app from play console (all tracks)....even from beta and internal test track.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue.
1)I removed all testers those are assign in tracks
2)delete all draft apks in Artifact library
3)upload new apk in all tracks.